# What does SSL attempt to prevent?

Tags: ssl

Consider a situation where networking endpoint 1 opens a SSL connection to networking endpoint 2, endpoint 1 sends some data (which gets encrypted), endpoint 1 closes the connection.

When an entity views data on the underlying connection, (eg. an ISP, or when within range of a wireless networking device, or a program monitoring another program), it is likely that the entity was able to view the data from the start of the underlying connection thus having access to all the data of the underlying connection.

Surely an entity could just automate the decryption process using the data ripped from the underlying connection, rendering SSL pointless at preventing this type of hack.

I can't see how this makes it harder by much at all for the majority of people to read the unencrypted data, people could just download software that monitors connections to read all data and decrypt it, or by using SSL APIs.

So what does SSL attempt to prevent?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Key_exchange_or_key_agreement  you're asking questions you could easily find the answers for with minimal googling.

Comment: This is just way to broad a question. I’d suggest you start by reading on Wikipedia or elsewhere on the net about the basics of TLS.

Comment: If a client can open an SSL connection from any network to encrypt and decrypt data over it, surely this can be spoofed by the man in the middle attack if they were monitoring all data on the underling connection. eg. TCP.

Comment: @Mex No. Oddly enough, they thought of that. In about 1990.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSL provides three basic security features:

- Authentication. The peer is who he says he is. This prevents MITM attacks.
- Privacy aka confidentiality. No-one else can read the messages. This prevents all passive attacks.
- Integrity. No-one else can *write* messages into the channel. This prevents injection attacks.

It also provides a means whereby the application can perform a fourth function:

- Authorization. The peer identity established by authentication can be used by the application to determine whether that identity is authorized to use the part of the application requested.

Comment: Thanks, that's really useful. But regarding SSL Authentication, why can't a fake server spoof a real server's certificate when the server gives the certificate to the client? (Stage 2 here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/326574/mutualssl.png)

Comment: Because it can't sign the handshake messages with the server's private key, because it doesn't  have it, so it can't prove to the peer that it owns the certificate, so the handshake would fail.